# EFI partition empty after grub-install

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

After running into a weird issue with my Linux Mint install, I decided that the easiest fix was to re-install it. After a re-install I had nothing but a BusyBox shell, and decided that it was probably a Grub issue. After which I proceeded to try and use boot-repair to fix it. it didn't work, and now I have a system that on startup gives a BIOS-styled "No bootable drive or boot failed".
I have in the process of 2 days of trying to fix it formatted my EFI partition enough times to leave it empty.
Gparted shows the following:

```
fat32 100Mib flags=boot,esp  
unknown 16Mib flags=msftres (random Win10 partition)  
ntfs 53.98GiB flags=msftdata (Win10 install partition)  
linux-swap 3.81GiB flags=swap (Swap for Mint)  
ext4 57.57GiB no flags (Linux Mint install)  
ntfs 1.00GiB flags=msftdata (Recovery partition for Win10)
unallocated 1.00MiB
```

How do I make at least Win10 bootable (I think I know what to do from there, as when I first installed Mint, I had to do this).
If any additional info is needed, I can only get what is obtainable through Mint Live.
Edit: BootInfo Summary: http://sprunge.us/JquNnB
Update: Windows is back, Boot-Repair gives `NVRAM locked` error.

Comment: For Windows you will need a Windows repair disk to restore boot files & UEFI boot entry. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair            
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Boot-Repair cannot fix Windows issues, and most often offers a grub menu update or a total reinstall of grub if system looks ok.

Comment: @oldfred I have added the BiS link.

Comment: You have an UEFI system and UEFI install of Windows. But show no boot files in ESP - efi system partition, your sda1. That needs Windows repairs to reinstall its boot files. Be sure to boot Windows repair flash drive in UEFI mode. You also show grub in gpt's protective MBR for BIOS boot. But now have the mount of the ESP in fstab, so Ubuntu now in UEFI boot mode. Just to not try to boot in BIOS mode as then it will just give grub? as BIOS in grub will not work. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Comment: @oldfred I have successfully gotten Win10 to work, and now am trying to bring GRUB back up. I boot into Mint Live, install ppa boot-repair and run it. recommended fix (worked for me when I just started dual booting) but it gives NVRAM locked error.

Comment: Do you have a setting in UEFI that prevents updates to NVRAM? It may be separate from UEFI Secure boot or Secure boot may do that. What brand/model system? Lenovo Thinkpad E531 - turn off locked boot order setting in UEFI
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2255746 Fujitsu lifebook ah512. Secure boot options blocked in bios - UEFI password required
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2171114

Comment: Acer Spin 1 32N Uses really old looking BIOS, and I dont think it has any of those.

Comment: Acer often needed you to set "trust". Acer Spin 5 Ubuntu Needs Acer password & trust Older answer, but same issues? 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238

Comment: That worked, thank you! Do you know how to remove extra entries in BIOS? I have 2 Windows Boot Managers. and 2 grubs that dont work/I dont need.

Comment: See `man efibootmgr`. More details here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228  If you set UEFI password, never forget it, or reset back to blank.